# Operators >> and << in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in javascript:

```
        for(i=0;i<imax;i+=4)
    {
        b10=(_getbyte64(s,i)<<18) | (_getbyte64(s,i+1)<<12) | (_getbyte64(s,i+2)<<6) | _getbyte64(s,i+3);

        x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10>>16,(b10>>8)&255,b10&255))
    }
```

and I'm trying to create the same code in PHP but I don't know what does mean of operators **>>** and **<<** ?

I did this test:

```
var test = 4;

if ( test >> 3 ) // >> operator
{
    alert('yee');
}
```

And finally alert doesn't show on screen. But when I try in this way:

```
var test = 4;

if ( test > 3 ) // > operator
{
    alert('yee');
}
```

And then on my screen I can see an alert with text: "yee".
So where is diference between operators **>>** and **>** ??

Thanks.

Comment: >> is right shift operator.  << is left shift.  >>> is unsigned right shift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So where is diference between operators >> and > ??

About the same as between "app" and "apple".

`>` is a Boolean operator that tests for "greater than" - `a > b` is true if `a` is bigger than `b`, and `false` otherwise.

`>>` is a bit-shift-right operator. `a >> b` is `a / (2^b)` (with integral division); so `4 >> 3` is `4 / (2^3) = 4 / 8 = 0`, which is falsy in PHP. It basically cuts off the last `b` binary digits.

`<<` is the reverse, bit-shift-left. `a << b` is `a * (2^b)`, so `4 << 3` is `4 * (2^3) = 4 * 8 = 32`. It basically pads the number with `b` binary digits from the right side (`4` is binary `100`, if you shift it 3 bits left you get `100000`, which is `32`).

Comment: Does that make >>> an apple app 

Comment: So I can't using this operators in PHP, yes? How I can change this operators in PHP to using it in the same way?

Comment: Of course [you can](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Answer (score 1):

THe < and > are simple logical operators to check if they are greater than or less than other numbers.

Where as >> and << are binary shift operators, the >> operator will take the number in the left hand side and convert it into binary and then shift the digits towards right by the number present in the right hand side.

example 6 >> 1 will convert 6 into binary, i.e 00000110 and shift the digits towards right by 1, i.e, 00000011 and give the result as 3.

And << will similarly shift the digits towards left.

Answer (score 0):

> So where is diference between operators >> and > ?

`>>` and `<<` are known as [bit shift operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7f48wx9%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). They shift the bits of whatever you're targeting relative to the direction of the operator.

`>` and `<` are known as [boolean operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) and they compare two items together; they are your average "greater than" and "less than" signs.

**Side Note:**

I also want to point out why the code you had earlier didn't alert; it is because when you shift `4` 3 bits to right right, it becomes `0` or `false` in this case:

```
var test = 4;

// 4 = 100 in binary
// 100 >> 1 => 010
// 100 >> 2 => 001
// 100 >> 3 => 000
if ( test >> 3 ) // test >> 3 will return 0 or false, causing the alert to not fire
{
    alert('yee');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) about bitwise operators in javascript